# Why can a kernel mode driver not allocate and use memory without causing potential instability?

Tags: driver, windows-kernel, stability, kernel-mode

I'm learning about writing kernel-mode code. I keep seeing this notion of system stability being fragile in this mode of operation. I'm looking for a low level explanation of why that is.

I understand some ways code running in kernel mode code could certainly cause problems:

- kernel-mode code can write to any memory address, which might include corrupting memory used by a user-mode process
- or even modify memory relied on by the kernel to perform critical tasks.
- can communicate directly with hardware (which is just another feature of memory access)

But these seem like things one could avoid by simply allocating a safe memory space to work in, and generally not writing over any memory allocated to another process unless the process is specifically designed to share this memory.

I'll reference something I just read in the Windows documentation:

> **Important** A driver should not allocate memory "on the side" and use it as a kernel-mode stack. This has never been a recommended
> practice for any platform, because it affects the stability and
> reliability of the operating system. On x64-based systems, if the
> operating system detects an unauthorized kernel-mode stack, it will
> generate a bug check and shut down the system. - [Guidelines for using the kernel-mode stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn613940(v=vs.85))

Why is this the case?

Can a driver not simply allocate some unused memory which the rest of the system will know not to use?

Comment: Allocating memory is fine, the warning is highly specific to a driver setting up its own stack.  Stack overflows are very nasty, they named a popular programmers' web site after it.  It would allow a userland program to crash the kernel rather easily, the kernel can do something about it when it created the stack itself and knows its limits.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating memory in kernel (on heap) is common practice, there are a lot of functions to do that.

if you need to use big size data, it is recommended you allocate memory in the right pool and not use variables on stack.